Where are chemical potential windows [μR, μL] in the transmission spectra?
According to finite bias Non-Equilibrium Green’s Function (NEGF) method within the Landauer–Büttiker formula:
$$
I = \frac{2e}{h} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} T(E) \left( f(E - \mu_L) - f(E - \mu_R) \right) dE
$$
where T(E) is transmission at E, f(E) is the Fermi-Dirac distribution, and
μL and μR are the chemical potential of left and right electrodes,
respectively. Assuming electron flow from the left to the right electrode,
the bias voltage is Vb = μL- μR, and the current is evaluated by integrating
the transmission within the energy range μR < E < μL.
When we apply bias voltages to our device, where are chemical potential windows [μR, μL] in the transmission spectra? Could we know the positions of μR and μL in the transmission spectra from the transiesta outputs?

What does your Assuming ..  in the bias windows paragraphs add to the question, I don't see a reason for you to mix in semi-conductors, in your question, no? I think it will only confuse. Also, this is not necessarily a siesta related question.

Yes,it is not necessary to claim[    Assuming ..  in the bias windows]，but I think it's easier to make my point with semiconductors because of the existence of band gap, therefore, band gap in transmission function.

Hmm, I disagree, the point is that you don't know where uR and uL are in the transmission spectra, no? That has nothing to do with the electronic structure.

No, I don't know where uR and uL are in the transmission spectra. I agree with you, Sir. But I do think it is related with transiesta because maybe the positions  of uR and uL are included in the transiesta output.

The NEGF implemented in Siesta, as well as in other DFT codes are generally handling this quite similarly.

Initially there is a step that calculates the electronic structure without any electrodes. This is a pre-step required to get a good initial guess of the electronic structure of the device and its coupling to the electrodes.

I would encourage users to always think about why this step is really necessary?
Users should think about what happens when going from a regular DFT calculation, to an NEGF one. The primary difference is the semi-infinite electrodes, which by construction is already converged.
So, how would SCF steps look like if you started from an electronic structure far from the converged one, as compared to one that resembles the final device electronic structure?


Once step 1. has completed, we now have the electronic structure. With this we also have the Fermi level of the device region (IMPORTANT: but the Fermi level is without electrodes!).

We now start the NEGF calculation, with the necessary SCF steps. Solving the Poisson equation with proper boundary conditions, and by adding the electrode self-energies. At this point there is no such thing as a Fermi-level. The Fermi-level should encompass the full system, electrode + device. But we only have the small device, and estimate how the electrodes changes the electronic structure for the device.
Hence, the Fermi-level becomes a reference energy, denote $E_R$. It is often referred to as the Fermi-level, but it is in fact not the Fermi level (one should be able to see this after reading the full answer).

The electrodes chemical potentials are defined with respect to the reference energy level ($E_R$). So if you have $\mu_L = V/2$ and $\mu_R=-V/2$, then the bias window lies between $[E_R + V/2 ; E_R - V/2]$.
Alternatively, one could define the chemical potentials as $\mu_L = 0$, and $\mu_R =V$. In this case the bias window would lie between $[E_R ; E_R + V]$.


NEGF calculators will generally shift everything with respect to the reference energy level. And thus the bias window, when looking at $\mathrm{DOS}$, $T(E)$, etc. will generally be $[\mu_L ; \mu_R]$, however they are then defined (generally $V/2$ and $-V/2$).
The point about the reference energy is quite important for some systems. Typically users will create somewhat symmetric junctions, so the amount of atoms to the left of the actual scatterers, will be very close to the number of atoms to the right of the scatterers. In this case it makes sense to use the default $V/2$ and $-V/2$ chemical potentials. This is so, because the offset in the potential of the entire calculation will likely be very close to the initial reference level (Fermi-level in the pure DFT calculation, step 1).
However, imagine you had lots more atoms to the left of the scatterers. In this case the majority of the atoms potential will follow the left electrode's potential (forcefully added via the self-energies!).
In such a scenario one could imagine much faster convergence by setting $\mu_L = 0$ and $\mu_R=V$. Since then the global potential need not shift too much during the SCF steps.
The point here is that one will have a hard time defining the actual Fermi level, since it is position dependent, to the left, it is close to $\mu_L$, to the right it is close to $\mu_R$.
Bottom-line, the chemical potentials are located at the energies corresponding to their definitions in the input. And they are defined with respect to the reference energy level, $E_R$, which typically is the Fermi level from the pure DFT calculation.
For instance, the following input:
%block TS.ChemPots
  Left
  Right
%endblock TS.ChemPots

%block TS.ChemPot.Left
  mu 0 eV
  ...
%endblock TS.ChemPot.Left
%block TS.ChemPot.Right
  mu V
  ...
%endblock TS.ChemPot.Right

defines the $E_R=0$ and the bias window to be in the [0 ; V] range.

That solved my problem! Sir!
